# Unable to establish database connection to SQL Server 2008 using test java program

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am studying Core Java Volume 2 Advanced Features. I have to connect to any database to execute the source code in Database Programming chapter. I cannot share the  whole source code probably because of copyright issues. But basically I am trying to connect to SQL Server with a  simple TestDb java program and the connection properties such as DriverName, DB Url , Username and Password are located in a db.properties file as follows:

```
#jdbc.drivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433    ;databaseName=COREJAVA;int‌​egratedSecurity=true"
jdbc.username="sa"
jdbc.password="123456"
```

The code for connection is present in the `getConnection()` function as follows:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, IOException
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("database.properties")))
    {
        props.load(in);
    }
    String drivers = props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
    if (drivers != null) System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", drivers);
    String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
    String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
    String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");

    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

I fixed the error of TCP first thanks to this stackpost
[JDBC connection failed, error: TCP/IP connection to host failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841744/jdbc-connection-failed-error-tcp-ip-connection-to-host-failed)

But now when I run the program using the following command from cmd:

```
java -cp .;sqljdbc4.jar test.TestDB
```

I get the following stacktrace:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user '"sa"'. ClientConnectionId:2986bb7f-4f57-4932-b4c1-614ab3684ee0
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at test.TestDB.getConnection(TestDB.java:68)
        at test.TestDB.runTest(TestDB.java:35)
        at test.TestDB.main(TestDB.java:19)
```

I have referred to [Java connection to a SQL Server Database: Login failed for user 'sa'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877857/java-connection-to-a-sql-server-database-login-failed-for-user-sa)

I have IPALL port set to 1433, TCP/IP enabled in Server Configuration Manager and I am able to login normally using SQL server management studio with the 'sa' account. I am using the latest sqljdbc4.jar from Microsoft's website.

Comment: Perhaps try `integratedSecurity=false` since you're trying to log in as `sa` anyway.

Comment: @GordThompson I tried without the integrated security property and even tried by adding another property instance='SQLExpress' I still get the same error. :(

Comment: Okay, try removing the double quotes from around the username and password in your properties file, e.g., `dbc.username=sa` instead of `dbc.username="sa"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GordThompson thank you! I removed the double quotes from both username and password making

```
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=123456
```

And it is connecting to the database now!