# I can connect to on-premise sql through python but not with pyspark , why?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

i am using databricks with pyspark, i am doing some test to connect to on-premise databases and i find a problem : i can do it with python but no with pyspark.
for example this code with python and pymssql  works and i can get data later  :

```
import pymssql
try:
    conn = pymssql.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=db
    )
except Exception as e:
 print("An error occurred while connecting to SQL Server:", e)
```

but this codes does not work

```
df = spark.read \
.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:1433;database={db};user={user};password={password}") \
    .option("dbtable", db) \
    .load()
```

the credential are the same , i have tried many ways, with many drivers, jars, etc. Has anyone had something similar happen? could it be a networking error? the error is always  "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ... "
thanks

### SOLUTION

```
integrated_security = 'true'
authentication_scheme = "NTLM"
url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:{port};database={nombre};integratedSecurity={integrated_security};authenticationScheme={authentication_scheme}"

query = f"(SELECT TOP 10 * FROM {table}) AS subquery"

jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", query) \
    .option("user", f'{user_solo}@{domain}') \
    .option("password", clave) \
    .load()
```

Comment: Do any of these variables have special characters?

Comment: Or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769241) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24320153)

Comment: no, they does not have special characters, only the user is like "Domain\User".
i used the "integratedSecurity=true" but keeps returning the same error

Comment: Try using arguments from the other answers I shared above, and see if that works.

Comment: thanks, i can connect now, the error was raised because i was not using integrated_security  and i was setting the user like {domain}\{user} insted of {user}@{domain}